# How do I modify the URL generated during Backbone sync, but only for a specific requests

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to change the URL generated when my entity calls destroy. Instead of writing an HTTP DELETE to /{Action}/{EntityID}, I would like to send /{Action}/{EntityID}/{SecondEntityID}.

```
item.destroy({
    data: $.param({
        playlistId: playlistId
    }),
    processData: true,
    success: callback,
    error: function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

I thought that something like this might work, but it doesn't seem to append on any additional parameters. Do I have to implement my own sync method in its entirety if I want to extend just destroys' URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override is through passing in a .url property in options when you call destroy. Since I assume you'd want to do this for every single call, you can do this:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  destroy: function(options) {
    // Override URL
    options || (options = {});
    // You can put whatever you need here,
    options.url = 'http://www.awesome.com/destroy/' + this.get('id') + '/' + this.get('secondaryId');

    // Call Model.destroy().
    // We are reusing the existing functionality from Backbone.Model.destroy().
    Backbone.Model.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments); 
  }
});

var m= new MyModel({ id: 123, secondaryId: 456 });

// Note: You need to set 'id' in order for destroy() call to be successful.
m.destroy({
  sucess: function() { console.log('good'); },
  error: function() { console.log('bad'); }
});
```

If you open up Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools, you should see an XHR/AJAX call was made to www.awesome.com.

Since you mentioned that you want to do this across ALL entities that you have, what you can do in that case is to create a `BaseModel` in your application, and have all your entities extend from it.

Anyway, hope this helps!

JSFiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/EwQaD/